Points on your driver's licese in the state of Florida and driving School
It is my understanding that  in the state of Florida you  can go to driver's school to have points removed from your driver's license. However, you can only do that 5 times in your lifetime. Am I  right so far?
Now suppose a person is living  in another state and then moves to Florida. In his home state he has gone to driving school twice. Can he still go to driving school another 5 times in Florida, if needed, to get rid of points?

I did some googling and wasn't able to find a definitive answer. But IMHO, anyone who gets so many traffic violations that this is an issue shouldn't be on the road in the first place.

@Barmar Is a ticket every 6 years so bad?

No, but why would you need to go to traffic school for that? I don't think the points from a single ticket will raise your insurance rate. Don't the points expire automatically in FL?

@Barmar it's always been my understanding that any points is a detriment for insurance purposes, so it's always beneficial to keep your record clean if possible. Recalling back to driver's ed for NJ, points on your license expire after 2 years of no additional violations, but insurance companies tend to have a look back period of 7 years.

@Barmar also to put into context 'driving school', when I got a ticket in FL years ago, I nullified the points by completing an online class that took an hour (and absolutely no less than hour).

@Barmar I like the idea of having no points on my license. That is why I would go to driver school.
